# About an error term in Prime Counting Function

Tags: prime-numbers, math-history, distribution-of-primes

We know since ancient greeks that:

$$\pi(N)=N - \sum_p \left\lfloor \frac N p \right\rfloor + E(N)$$

Who was the first one to bound that $E(N)$? Which advances on it were made since then?

Comment: $\sum_p \lfloor \frac {N} {p} \rfloor $ isn't a useful approximation to the prime counting function. I think already Euclid knew this. It soon will becoame larger than x. Read [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) about $\pi(x)$

Comment: $$\sum_p \lfloor N /p \rfloor = \sum_p \sum_n 1_{pn \le N} =\sum_n \pi(N/n) $$ @miracle173

Comment: @miracle173 Corrected, thank you.

Comment: I still don't think this is right. Besides that: I think the questions is much too broad, there is another site(http://hsm.stackexchange.com/) dedicated to history of mathematics